# Error Replace Backslashes with Forward Slashes in string with number Python

Tags: python, string, backslash

I'd like to error-proof user input to a file reading function. Suppose the user input string has backslashes `sqlfile_in_DS="I:\DS\40-400\OppMetrics.sql"` and I want the corrected string to replace those with forward slashes `sqlfile_in_DS="I:/DS/40-400/OppMetrics.sql"`. In my attempts, the substring "/40" disappears.

Attempts and results:

```
1) print(pathlib.PureWindowsPath(sqlfile_in_DS))
OUTPUT:
I:/DS -400/OppMetrics.sql
    
2) print(sqlfile_in_DS.replace('\\','/'))
OUTPUT:
I:/DS -400/OppMetrics.sql
```

I used the answers from [[Replace Backslashes with Forward Slashes in Python]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119166/replace-backslashes-with-forward-slashes-in-python), [Converting a string variable to a regular expression in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60905179/converting-a-string-variable-to-a-regular-expression-in-python)

If the string is a raw string literal both methods work:

```
sqlfile_in_DS=r"I:\DS\40-400\OppMetrics.sql"
print(pathlib.PureWindowsPath(sqlfile_in_DS))
print(sqlfile_in_DS.replace('\\', '/'))

OUTPUT:
I:/DS/40-400/OppMetrics.sql
```

I can't find a good explanation for converting a simple string to a raw string that works. [Python regex: How to search and replace strings](https://flexiple.com/python/python-regex-replace/) doesn't

```
print(sqlfile_in_DS.encode('unicode_escape'))
OUTPUT:
b'I:\\\\DS -400\\\\OppMetrics.sql'

print(r'{}'.format(sqlfile_in_DS))
OUTPUT:
I:\DS -400\OppMetrics.sql
```

Comment: You don't EVER need to "convert" a string to a raw string.  Raw strings are just a way to represent string constants within a Python script.  If you read a string from a file, then it does not have any extra backslashes.  It's already in the right format.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question if the string has a backslash. Clearly, converting to a raw string would solve the problem.

Comment: There is *no such thing* as a "raw string".  There are "raw string literals", but that only applies to strings written directly in your source code; the resulting string object is exactly the same kind of string as any other.

Comment: Solve WHAT problem?  You haven't said a thing about what PROBLEM you are trying to solve.  Raw strings are not the issue.  The difference between a string and a raw string is the same as the difference between typing `100` and `0x64` to get an integer.  Both are ways to type an integer constant in code, but if you read a 100 from a file as a 4-byte integer, clearly it is neither in decimal or hexadecimal.  What end result are you trying to get?